# Simplify $E(\max(X_1+Y_1, X_2+Y_2))$ when $X_1, Y_1, X_2$, and $Y_2$ are exponentially distributed

Tags: probability-theory

> The time until A arrives is exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda_1$, and the time until B arrives is exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda_2$. Once they arrive, they will spend exponentially distributed times, with respective rates $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ before departing. What is the expected time of the last departure?

**(Try)**
I tried to Simplify $E(\max(X_1+Y_1, X_2+Y_2))$ when $X_1,Y_1,X_2$, and $Y_2$ are exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda_1$, $\mu_1$, $\lambda_2$, and $\mu_2$ respectively.

Let $L$ be the time of the last departure.

Let $A$ be the additional time.

\begin{align*}
E(\max(X_1+Y_1, X_2+Y_2))
 = E(L)
&= E(\max(X_1,Y_1)) \\
&\hspace{2em} + E(A \mid \text{A arrives first}) P(\text{A arrives first}) \\
&\hspace{2em} + E(A \mid \text{B arrives first}) P(\text{B arrives first}).
\end{align*}

I got the result of $E(\max(X_1,Y_1))$ by using calculus, but I don't know how to get the two conditional expectations: $E(A \mid \text{A arrives first})$ and $E(A \mid \text{B arrives first})$.
I need some hep. 
I'm also curious to know that is there a better way to get $E(\max(X_1+Y_1, X_2+Y_2))$.

Comment: Mathematica states that the answer is $(b c^2 (b + c) d^2 (b + d) + a c (b + c) d (b + d) (c d + b (c + d)) +
  a^3 (c^2 d^2 + b^3 (c + d) + b c d (c + d) + b^2 (c + d)^2) + 
 a^2 (c^2 d^2 (c + d) + b^3 (c + d)^2 + b^2 (c + d)^3 + 
    b c d (c^2 + 3 c d + d^2)))/(a b c (a + c) (b + c) d (a + d) (b + 
   d))$, where $a,b,c,d$ denote respectively $\lambda_1$, $\mu_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\mu_2$.

Comment: Please try to typeset your question using $\LaTeX$. It provides better readability.

Answer (score 1):

Since $L \geq 0$, you can write

$$ \Bbb{E}[L] = \int_{0}^{\infty} \Bbb{P}(L > t) \, \mathrm{d}t. $$

Now notice that for $t > 0$,

$$ \Bbb{P}(L > t) = 1 - \Bbb{P}(L \leq t) = 1 - \Bbb{P}(X_1+Y_1 \leq t)\Bbb{P}(X_2+Y_2 \leq t). $$

The latter one can be simplified by using convolution formula or whichever argument you prefer, and the result is

$$ \Bbb{P}(L > t) = 1 - \left(1 - \frac{e^{-\mu_1 t}\lambda_1 - e^{-\lambda_1 t}\mu_1}{\lambda_1 - \mu_1} \right)\left(1 - \frac{e^{-\mu_2 t}\lambda_2 - e^{-\lambda_2 t}\mu_2}{\lambda_2 - \mu_2} \right). $$

Plugging this back and integrating yields the following answer:

\begin{align*}
\Bbb{E}[L]
&= \frac{1}{\lambda_1}+\frac{1}{\lambda_2}+\frac{1}{\mu_1}+\frac{1}{\mu_2} \\
&\qquad + \frac{1}{(\lambda_1-\mu_1)(\lambda_2-\mu_2)} \left(
\frac{\lambda_2 \mu_1}{\lambda_1+\mu_2}
+\frac{\lambda_1 \mu_2}{\lambda_2+\mu_1}
-\frac{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}{\mu_1+\mu_2}
-\frac{\mu_1 \mu_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}
\right).
\end{align*}